# Local and Private IP Issue on Wamp Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, web-server, ip, apache-2.4

I'm having some problem regarding wamp server and my IP Address. In our company we have a machine that has a LOCAL IP of 192.168.x.xxx so basically we have wamp installed on it and every PC on the local network can access the websites hosted on it. However, that machine as also a PUBLIC IP of 116.50.xxx.xxx which when accessed on the outside network you can still access the websites hosted on it (C:/wamp/www) which I think shouldn't be happening. Is there a way that whenever I tried to access the Public IP there's a password prompt or something that will block the access using the public IP? Thanks

Comment: `192.168.x.xxx` <--- that isn't a public IP address.

Comment: That is just an example . Won't discuss the real public ip here.

Comment: Well pick another RFC1918 range, then. As it looks right now, your private and public IPs are in the same subnet, which is broken for many reasons.

Comment: So that means it hasn't something to do with the wamp server itself?

Comment: You should know: WAMP is for development use only. It's incredibly insecure, and should not be used in production under any circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a HTTP Basic authentication:

```
<Location />
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Secured"
  AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
  Require valid-user
  Satisfy any
  Deny from all
  Allow from 192.168.1
</Location>
```

To generate the `.htpasswd` file:

```
$ htpasswd -c /path/to/.htpasswd username-1
```

And to add additional users:

```
$ htpasswd /path/to/.htpasswd username-2
```

[Apache docs: htpasswd - Manage user files for basic authentication](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/htpasswd.html)

Comment: Is this applicable to a Windows Server Machine?

Comment: Tried it and worked perfectly on my local. Will try it in the server. Thanks